# Linux server has high ping on some clients

Tags: linux, networking, java

Some clients that have connected to a server of mine keep saying that they have extremely high ping and keep disconnecting from the server (yes, it's a minecraft server but it also hosts fileservers, bots, and other stuff) even though some clients have very fast connection. I've talked with the people who've had bad connection and it seems that they have excellent connection to other servers which are located much further away from them, and should have a higher ping than our server.

As I have little to no knowledge on how I should start troubleshooting this, how could I start and what could be the possible causes for high ping and disconnections for some clients?

### This far I have the following info:

- server has free ram (alot)
- server is not using it's full processing power
- some clients have very high and some very low even when connected at the same time, within a similar location in real life
- server has been restarted
- swap memory has been decreased
- server is hosted on IPV4 port
- lagging clients connect directly to server without VPNs
- no nginx or similar services are currently running
- necessary server ports are opened with UFW
- server has free bandwidth (checked from hetzners website)
- lagging clients have ipv4 addresses, but so do non-lagging clients
- some clients keep disconnecting at random intervals (every few minutes)
- servers use Java
- server software has been updated to latest versions
- some netty network packets keep corrupting (for example: "Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.IOException: Packet 0/31 (ty) was larger than I expected, found 10280 bytes extra whilst reading packet 31" Not all errors are like this, some just say that the client was simply disconnected)

### Here's what `ifconfig` prints out a few minutes after a reset (ipv addresses have been altered a bit)

```
enp35s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 95.217.120.173  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast 95.217.120.191
        inet6 2a01:000:00:0000::2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::aaa1:0000:0000:8e5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a8:a1:00:00:00:e5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1562223  bytes 109572401 (104.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4615944  bytes 4081321353 (3.8 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xf7200000-f727ffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2945629  bytes 7593571263 (7.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2945629  bytes 7593571263 (7.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

### The current DNS settins are as follows:

**For minecraft:**

SRV Record
_minecraft _tcp 0 5 25565 mc.karanteeni.net

A Record
mc 95.217.120.173

(taken from namecheap dns)

**For www:**

(default github guideline settings)

**Others:**

URL Redirect Record  http://95.217.120.173:<port>/ <Masked/Unmasked>

### Running `tracert mc.karanteeni.net`

Running the command on my machine without high ping gives the following result:

```
1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  home [192.168.1.1]
  2     6 ms     6 ms     6 ms  dsl-trebng21-58c180-2.dhcp.inet.fi [88.193.000.0]
  3     9 ms     8 ms     8 ms  141.208.000.000
  4     9 ms     9 ms     8 ms  62.115.000.00
  5     9 ms    10 ms     9 ms  hls-b3-link.ip.twelve99.net [62.115.000.000]
  6    10 ms    10 ms    10 ms  hetzner-svc076536-ic365572.ip.twelve99-cust.net [62.115.52.255]
  7    11 ms    10 ms    10 ms  core32.hel1.hetzner.com [213.239.203.209]
  8    10 ms    11 ms    10 ms  ex9k1.dc4.hel1.hetzner.com [213.239.252.98]
  9    10 ms    10 ms    10 ms  static.173.120.217.95.clients.your-server.de [95.217.120.173]
```

Running the command on the other owners machine which now has very high ping:

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms     2 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.1.1]
  2   120 ms    70 ms   181 ms  46-163-000-0.blcnet.fi [46.000.000.0]
  3     7 ms    13 ms    16 ms  46-163-000-000.blcnet.fi [46.163.000.000]
  4     6 ms     6 ms     8 ms  46-163-000-000.blcnet.fi [46.163.000.000]
  5     8 ms    12 ms     9 ms  85.194.000.00
  6    13 ms    14 ms    14 ms  87.236.154.178
  7    16 ms    12 ms    13 ms  87.236.154.212
  8    83 ms   271 ms    56 ms  hetzner.ficix2.ficix.fi [193.110.224.44]
  9    14 ms    12 ms    15 ms  core32.hel1.hetzner.com [213.239.224.26]
 10    13 ms    12 ms    18 ms  ex9k1.dc4.hel1.hetzner.com [213.239.252.98]
 11   160 ms    14 ms    12 ms  static.173.120.217.95.clients.your-server.de [95.217.120.173]
```

### Results of running `netstat -s | egrep -i 'loss|retran'`

```
79234 segments retransmitted
TCPLostRetransmit: 7145
59 timeouts in loss state
58300 fast retransmits
6808 retransmits in slow start
TCPLossProbes: 8710
TCPLossProbeRecovery: 411
TCPSynRetrans: 2691
```

Comment: `ping`s are answered by the kernel though the network driver. Unless the server is hugely overloaded, the number and types of applications on the system don't enter into the ping times. If clients are reporting high ping times then there is usually a network issue somewhere between the client and the server. Do you possibly have a routing loop in your network?

Comment: @doneal24 i'm not exactly sure how to check if one exists but there shouldn't be. the client connects to port 25565 which is a proxy that then reconnects to local closed port 255XX after verifying user login from Microsoft servers. no other connections to other servers should be made, except for locally hosted MySQL database.
the other owner of the server moved to a new house and just set up their pc and it seems that they also have this issue now but all other servers seem to work fine, their pc is also set up as before they had high ping times

Comment: A `traceroute` from the servers that have a high 'ping' should give some insight on where in the network there might be a longer delay.

Comment: @LjmDullaart I ran ```tracert``` on my and my friends windows machines and I've added the results to the post. It seems they have very high ping at the beginning and when connecting to hetzner (the server which has very high ping), but I'm not sure how I could continue from here as to my understanding the problem is somewhere else rather than the server and the lagging clients machines?

Comment: 10ms is pretty good across the Internet. 160ms not so good. I'd suspect congestion myself

Comment: @roaima the problem is that some clients have pings between 500-9000ms, which is VERY unsustainable, and after creating a poll it seems almost half of the people seem to be having this problem who answered this poll. Edit after you edited your comment: the server did not get congested with ~40 simultaneous connections, but with lagging clients it seems they have high ping even if they're the only one connected

Comment: I wasn't meaning to suggest the congestion is on your server: even a highly loaded server should be able to respond to ping quite easily. It would be interesting to see if the issue is related to links from Finland to Germany, or other countries too. Similarly, when there's congestion for your friends get them to try pinging another German Hetzner server too. Finally, if you can, compare pings inbound to your server and pings from your server out.

Comment: The connection between the Asus router and the client's ISP seems to the problem. Also, step 8  seems a bit high. Not much you can do about that, except show the client where the problem is.